# Jboss Maven plugin takes too long to deploy

Tags: maven, build, jboss, jboss7.x

I use the Maven auto-deploy plugin to auto deploy to the Jboss application server. 
The deployment plugin is configured as shown below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
    <configuration>
       <hostname>localhost</hostname>
       <port>9999</port>
       <filename>TestApp.war</filename>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
        </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The deployment does work but the problem is that it takes quite a while for the deployment to take place. It is as though it is waiting for something to happen. I just stays there waiting and eventually it does complete.

When it gets to this point it gets stuck.

```
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.0.2.Final:deploy (default) @ TestApp---
[INFO] Executing goal deploy on server localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9999.
29-Feb-2012 15:52:15 org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.Beta2
29-Feb-2012 15:52:15 org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.0.Beta2
29-Feb-2012 15:52:15 org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.Beta2
[INFO]
```

In some cases it just gets stuck at the above point and nothing happens unless i press the Carriage Return key on the Jboss console for something to happen.

Environment

Maven 3
Jboss 7.0.2

Comment: What OS? I haven't heard about it hanging before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did some tests, with a small helloworld deployment, and didn't experience any slowness or hanging. The initial deployment took about 15 seconds and subsequent redploys took only a few seconds.

My test environment:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 09:31:09-0800)
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
- JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final certified web profile
- JBoss AS Maven Plugin 7.0.2.Final

Comment: It must be something on my machine then. Will investigate further. Thanks for running the simple test.